# EventSourceException in Application Insight

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-web-app-service

I'm getting this exception in Live Metrics Stream. 
When I'm debugging locally I can't see any warning or error. Checking the Failure blad also leads to nowhere. 
There is no track for this error in my logs.

> AI (Internal): [Microsoft-ApplicationInsights-Data]
>   EventSourceException while processing event "Message":
>   System.Reflection.TargetException:Non-static method requires a target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in Application Insights. The errors can safely be ignored according to the product team. If you would like to track the status of this issue, you can do so on their Github repo: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/issues/850